# adb logact is not showing onStop callbacks

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dalvik, dex

my phone is already rooted, and to make sure I have also tried in emulator.
The thing is I can see the `onPause`, `onResume` callback but I cannot see the `onStop` callbacks. Are there anything to enable or disable in `logcat` for it? I am exactly recreating the lifecycles so that `onStop` callbacks should be called.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to start another activity from current activity, you will see `onStop()` callback.

Comment: Hi, refer to my comment on the answer section.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: There would only be logging for this if you put it there - show the code you expect to create a log message.

Comment: You meant if I do not override the onStop call back I wont see this?

Answer (score -1):

When user exits the app by pressing back button on phone, onStop method() is called. When an activity is no longer visible to the user the also onStop() method is called. You can either exit the app by pressing the back button or you can start a new activity from this activity to show onStop() callback. Refer this link for ore information:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I said in my question "I am exactly recreating the lifecycles so that onStop callbacks should be called." I know about activity lifecycles, and I am recreating the scenerios to gurantee that onStop is called. My question is why logcat is not showing it while iti is showing onPause onResume etc.